# How can I add a value in my list when a condition is true?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict with alot of items:

```
{'id-quantity-60': u'1', 'id-quantity-35': u'3','id-product-35': u'on', 'id-product-60': u'on',}
```

I need to create a list with all three elements inside.
I'm expecting a list like this:

```
<type 'list'>: [['60', u'1', u'on'], ['35', u'3', u'on'],]
```

I have only 2 values above, but 2 times the same product-id. So it should add the quantity and the 'on off' together to the same product-id.

How can I do that? I tried it with something like this:

```
for key, value in request.params.items():
  if key[:12] == 'id-quantity-':
    if key[12:] in list:
      list.insert(key[12:], value)
    else:
      list.append([key[12:], value])

  if key[:11] == 'id-product-':
    if key[11:] in list:
      list.insert(key[11:], value)
    else:
      list.append([key[11:], value])
```

The problem is I get this list all time splitet:

```
<type 'list'>: [['60', u'1'], ['35', u'3'], ['35', u'on'], ['60', u'on'],]
```

finally I should be able to fill the data in here (**60, 1, True for** example):

`data = request.registry['website']._subscription_exclude_product(cr, uid, [{'product_id': int(60), 'qty': int(1), 'like': bool(True)}], context=context)`

Thank you very much.

Comment: `I need to create a list with all three elements inside.` Please describe how you compute these three elements.

Comment: Could you shorten your dict and give a better description of the expected result?

Comment: And when should it be off?

Comment: it should be off when it's like this = 'id-quantity-35': u'0' - zero

Comment: @stee I've updated the anser

Answer (score 0):

Assuming keys for quantity and product are in the same format across the dictionary:

```
d={'id-quantity-60': u'1', 'id-quantity-35': u'3','id-product-35': u'on', 'id-product-60': u'on',}

l=[]
for k,v in d.items():
    if 'id-quantity' in k:
        x = k.replace('id-quantity-','')
        y = 'id-product-'+str(x)
        l.append([x, v, d[y]])

print(l)
```

Output

```
[['60', '1', 'on'], ['35', '3', 'on']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input dictionary is in request.params variable,

```
quantity = {k.split("-")[-1]: v for k, v in request.params.items() if "quantity" in k}
product = {k.split("-")[-1]: v for k, v in request.params.items() if "product" in k}

result = [[k, v, product[k]]  for k, v in quantity.items()]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['60', '1', 'on'], ['35', '3', 'on']]
```

**Updated:** replace `result=...` with the following

```
result = [[k, v, True if product.get(k) else False]  for k, v in quantity.items()]
```

to get

```
[['35', '3', True], ['42', '0', False]]
```

if "id-product-42" is not in input dict.

Comment: your code is not working for me
`            quantity = {k.split("-")[-1]: a[k] for k in request.params.items() if "quantity" in k}
            product = {k.split("-")[-1]: a[k] for k in request.params.items() if "product" in k}

            result = [[k, v, product[k]] for k, v in quantity.items()]`

Comment: @stee Of course not. You replaced variable `a` with `request.params.items()` but do not replace others occurrences of `a`. I've updated the answer to fit your `request` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect?

```
products = {k.split('-')[-1]: v for k, v in x.items() if 'product' in k}
quantities = {k.split('-')[-1]: v for k, v in x.items() if 'quantity' in k}
all = [(k, v, 'on' if k in products else 'off') for k, v in quantities.items()]
```

Comment: and how can I fill these 3 values in my code for every product? `data = request.registry['website']._subscription_exclude_product(cr‌​, uid, [{'product_id': int(all[0]), 'qty': int(all[1]), 'like': bool(all[2])}], context=context)`

Comment: @stee, please be more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict() with a default list of 2 items to make it more flexible:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def default_list():
    return [None, None]

request = {'id-quantity-60': u'1', 'id-quantity-71': u'0', 'id-quantity-35': u'3','id-product-35': u'on', 'id-product-60': u'on'}
result = defaultdict(default_list)

for key, value in request.items():
  _, pattern, productid = key.split('-')

  if pattern == 'quantity':
    result[productid][0] = value
    result[productid][1] = 'on' if int(value) else 'off'
  elif pattern == 'product':
    result[productid][1] = value
```

Returns:

```
defaultdict(<function default_list at 0x7faa3d3efe18>,
            {'35': ['3', 'on'],
             '60': ['1', 'on'],
             '71': ['0', 'off']})
```

In case you really need a list:

```
resultList = [[k]+v for (k,v) in result.items()]
>>> [['60', '1', 'on'], ['71', '0', 'off'], ['35', '3', 'on']]
```

Comment: and how can I fill these 3 values in my code for every product?  
data = request.registry['website']._subscription_exclude_product(cr, uid, [{'product_id': int(resultList[0]), 'qty': int(resultList[1]), 'like': bool(resultList[2])}], context=context)